Generating an Azure Communication Services Token within an Android Studio App
I am attempting to follow the Azure Quickstart at Microsoft Learn, but when I get to the part about creating a User Access Token, I am unable to generate one by following the Java guidelines.
Here is the code I am trying to implement:
private void createAgent() {
    String connectionString = "<String connectionString = \"<endpoint=https://agentq-1984.unitedstates.communication.azure.com/";>";
    CommunicationIdentityClient communicationIdentityClient = new CommunicationIdentityClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
    List<CommunicationTokenScope> scopes = Arrays.asList(CommunicationTokenScope.VOIP);
    CommunicationUserIdentifierAndToken result = communicationIdentityClient.createUserAndToken(scopes);
    CommunicationUserIdentifier user = result.getUser();
    AccessToken accessToken = result.getUserToken();
    OffsetDateTime expiresAt = accessToken.getExpiresAt();

    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    String userToken = accessToken.getToken();
    try {
        CommunicationTokenCredential credential = new CommunicationTokenCredential(userToken);
        CallClient callClient = new CallClient();
        deviceManager = callClient.getDeviceManager(context).get();
        callAgent = callClient.createCallAgent(getApplicationContext(), credential).get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create call agent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

And I am having issues starting with 'CommunicationIdentityClient'. It seems that there is a lot of information about setting up the tokens and such for Java or Windows apps, but I cannot find an answer to setting one up for an Android app. I attempted to import the Azure Communication Service Android SDK, but that did not work.
Am I missing a library? Am I missing a class? Am I missing something else?

Could you include what error you are getting when you run the code?

Here is the solution I pieced together:
In 'build.gradle':
implementation libs.azure.communication.identity

In 'MainActivity':
CommunicationIdentityClient communicationIdentityClient = new com.azure.communication.identity.CommunicationIdentityClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
    com.azure.communication.common.CommunicationUserIdentifier user = communicationIdentityClient.createUser();

    List<CommunicationTokenScope> scopes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(CommunicationTokenScope.VOIP));
    AccessToken accessToken = communicationIdentityClient.getToken(user, scopes);
    OffsetDateTime expiresAt = accessToken.getExpiresAt();

    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    String userToken = accessToken.getToken();

